# while function for uppercase and lowercase letter input

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, seconds

int main()
{
    string word = "A";
    do
    {
    system("CLS");
    system("COLOR 3");
    cout<<"\nH";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"I ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"T";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"H";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"R";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E "<<endl<<endl;
    sleep_for(seconds(1));
    cout<<"H";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"O";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"W ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"A";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"R";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"Y";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"O";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"U? "<<endl<<endl;
    usleep(50000);
    sleep_for(seconds(1));
    cout<<"H";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"O";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"P";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"Y";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"O";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"U";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"'R";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"D";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"O";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"I";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"N";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"G ";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"G";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"R";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"E";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"A";
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"T"<<endl<<endl;
    usleep(50000);
    cout<<"A.Im doing great :)       B.Im sad :/"<<endl;

    cin>>word;
}
    while(word!="A"||word!="a"); //I want to let input be upper/lower case
    cout<<"this means its A and going for next command"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hi there, so basically Im a freshman on the university, studying Computer Science course, and I am trying to learn by myself (to be a step ahead than others)

In this program what my goal is to make a responsive machine: questions with a 2 or more answer option where if answer is not in context, system("CLS") is used then repeat question (loop). Decorations: "system color" for color, "usleep" for letter animation in words, "sleep_for" for gap between word line

1.How do I fix the while command where it couldnt detect if I put both condition
"while(word!="A"||word!="a");"
2.If there's a simpler way to **cout** words letter by letter, please do tell.

Comment: `word!="A"||word!="a"` is always true. Think about it. I mean what happens when word == "A"? Isn't `word!="a"` true?

Comment: Also this is very far from a minimal example. Next time please reduce the code to the minimal code that reproduces the issue. Here is a guide on what to include in your example code: [mcve]

Comment: I also recommend you study and use only the required #include statements for your code. You seem to be including a lot of stuff you don't need or want.

Comment: 1.I thought `word!="A" ||word!="a"` declares that if the input is not upper/lower case A then its going to loop ? 
2.Yeah I'm sorry, I didnt know where to look for guide in asking question
3.I'm basically compiling codes from research and modifying them into my goals. I do admit tho its kinda too much.

Comment: It will loop always because at least 1 of the to expressions will be true even when word == "A" or "a".

Comment: can I havr alternative or a fix to it?

Comment: Use && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

wrong > `while(word!="A"|| word!="a");`

fixed > `while(word!="A"&& word!="a");`

thanks to drescherjm